# How to save multiple req.body.name in one document Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am inserting a form in mongodb. Data is storing in collection successfully. but I have a user's company details as follow:

```
company:
[{companyname:req.body.companyname,
industry:req.body.industry,
jobtitle:req.body.jobtitle,
startdate:req.body.prevstartdate,
enddate:req.body.prevenddate,
roles:req.body.roles}]
```

And schema for this document is:

```
company: [{
            companyname:String,
            industry:String,
            jobtitle:String,
            startdate:Date,
            enddate:Date,
            roles:String,}]
```

In client view, user can append the company form till 5 times. So I want to know that how can I store the appended form's value in array and save in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Schema` allows only one `String` for each field.

you need to change it to `array of Strings`.

```
company: [{
            companyname: [String],
            industry:[String],
            jobtitle:[String],
            startdate:[Date],
            enddate:[Date],
            roles:[String]}]
```

And instead of inserting into the collection everytime, try inserting into it only if a document with that company name is not present, if it is already present, try updating that document. Push into each field while updating it.

See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/), how you can push into a document.

In short, i can show you how to use `$push`:

```
{ $push: {companyname:req.body.companyname,
          industry:req.body.industry,
          jobtitle:req.body.jobtitle,
          startdate:req.body.prevstartdate,
          enddate:req.body.prevenddate,
          roles:req.body.roles} 
 }
```

Comment: I am saving user professional details like below
`var addprofessionaldetails={
totalexperience:req.body.totalexperience,
employementtype:req.body.employementtype,
company:{ $push: {companyname:req.body.companyname,
          industry:req.body.industry,
          jobtitle:req.body.jobtitle,
          startdate:req.body.prevstartdate,
          enddate:req.body.prevenddate,
          roles:req.body.roles} 
   }
 };
 new userdetails({ 
   professionaldetails:addprofessionaldetails,
   }).save(function(err, cvdata)
    res.render('dashboard');});`

Comment: `new userdetails({ 
   professionaldetails:addprofessionaldetails,
   }).save(function(err, cvdata){
    if(err){res.json(err);}
    else{res.render('dashboard');}});`
    
 
after submiting, there are null values in all keys. and every key is creating its own array.

Comment: When you are creating a new user, try creating it normally. From the next time, update the user using `$push` .  It should be :
`$push:{ $company: {companyname:req.body.companyname, industry:req.body.industry, jobtitle:req.body.jobtitle, startdate:req.body.prevstartdate, enddate:req.body.prevenddate, roles:req.body.roles} } `

Comment: I want to save all records at only once using insert query. and I don't think $push operation can be execute in insert query

Comment: You want to insert multiple company data at one go?

Comment: And, $push can be used with update, not insert. Thats why i said while updating , you need to push into the document.

Comment: Yes I want to insert multiple company data along with user's other data in database and I am not going to update user's data.

Comment: does your `$req.body.companyname` contains multiple names? and similarly other field also contains multiple values?

Comment: I have multiple $req.body.companyname and each have different values. and want to insert in company key as an array in mongodb

Comment: is your `$req.body.companyname` an array or not? Otherwise how can you have muliple `$req.body.companyname`.